# Replace single quotes

Tags: google-forms

I am using Google Forms to get data and them importing it into Google Fusion Tables. The problem is if someone type an '. The script I am using is [here](https://github.com/lclontz/google_forms_to_fusion_tables/blob/master/script%20for%20Google%20forms.txt). Could I edit it to replace or remove all apostrophes before syncing? If it is possible I would prefer to do it inside of the Google Spreadsheet using some formula. I think I could also use another script just to do this but I am not really sure how to do that.

I am using the form to gather applications for dogs so people of all ages will be using it. I really wish I could just say don't use apostrophes but people will not always see that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What did you tried? Did you already take a look to [Google Forms input validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en) and to the [Google Sheets Function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)?

Comment: I forgot about that, I will try to see if that works. Thabks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure here is an easy way with JS:

**Working Fiddle**: https://jsbin.com/hosagu/3/edit?js,console

```
var str = "don't";
var test = "f's'a'g'd'a's'd'g'";

console.log(str.replace(/\'/g, "")); // "dont"

console.log(test.replace(/\'/g, "")); //"fsagdasdg"
```

As a 'Script' or function:

```
function REMOVEAPOSTROPHE (string) {
  return str.replace(/\'/g, "");
}
```

Comment: So would that be in a separate script and does it remove them from the spreadsheet in all columns?

Comment: yes, and no. You would need to follow the docs, I will edit the code to be a 'script' ready to go, but you have to make it work on the columns by calling it : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#getting_started

Comment: Sorry, I am still not exactly sure how to get it to work. I was able to use =REMOVEAPOSTROPHE(B2) to remove them but it copies the values into the new cell and does not change them in the old one (which is what I need.) Also if I try to run it it tells me "ReferenceError: "str" is not defined. (line 2, file "REMOVEAPOSTROPHE")" If I change that to 'string' it works then.

Comment: If I change that to 'string' it works then in the spreadsheet. If I try to run again it errors again with something about method call "replace" of undefined. Here is the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gDUMF6_nWrG9qNhWibtWboNX7mLdVafDdzf_u13MSrw/edit?usp=sharing A lot more of the colums will be filled in normally.

Comment: Instead of using code/formulas fix response it's better to [validate the answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en) before form submission.